# Convert Dictionary<int, ParentObject> to Dictionary<int, ChildObject> LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a parent class (let's call it `ParentClass`) that holds only a few properties (a `long` and `string` in this case) along with a class that inherits from it (let's call it `ChildClass`) which does not add any new properties, but only changes some of the method implementations.

In one method, I have a `Dictionary<int, ParentClass>` that I want to convert to a `Dictionary<int, ChildClass>`. Ideally I'd like to do this with LINQ, but here's my current implementation with a `foreach` loop:

```
bar = new Dictionary<int, ChildClass>();
foreach(var foo in parentDictionary) { //parentDictionary is Dictionary<int, ParentClass>
    bar.Add(foo.Key, new ChildClass() { Id = foo.Value.Id, Name = foo.Value.Name});
}
```

Is there a simple way to implement this conversion with LINQ to make it a one-liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` inherits from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so we can use any LINQ method:

```
parentDictionary.ToDictionary(
    kv => kv.Key,
    kv => new ChildClass { Id = kv.Value.Id, Name = kv.Value.Name });
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you could call `ToDictionary()` on a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially doing the same thing but you can use LINQs ToDictionary method like this:

```
bar = parentDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, new ChildClass() { Id = x.Value.Id, Name = x.Value.Name});
```